# htaccess rewrite url name

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been breaking my head over this one for almost 2 hours now.

I have a website (let's call it example.com)
And I need to rewrite this url:

example.com/plant.php?naam=Brahea%20Armata

To

example.com/Brahae_Armata

This is what my .htaccess file looks like atm:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com/plant.php?naam=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That doesn't work. Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Can there be multiple `%20` in URL?

Comment: No, I don't think I'll ever have two spaces in one URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /plant\.php\?naam=(.*)\%20(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1_%2? [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /plant\.php\?naam=(.*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) page.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Some pages don't contain a space in the URL.
Would it be correct to use the following code?

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /plant\.php\?naam=(.*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NE,R=301,L]